# Python threading: monitoring threads and executing additional code after threads complete

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have the following code:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, command, template, env, build_flavor, logger):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.command = command
        self.template = template
        self.env = env
        self.build_flavor = build_flavor
        self.logger = logger

    def run(self):
        self.logger.info('Running (%s)...this may take several minutes. Please be patient' % self.build_flavor)
        run_command(self.command, self.template, self.env)
        self.logger.info('Complete (%s)' % self.build_flavor)
        return
```

And then in another class, when I create the actual threads:

```
if self.build_type == 'default':
            threads = []
            for t in self.template:
                modify_template(t)
                build_flavor = self.getmatch(t)
                thread = MyThread(packer, t, self.new_env, build_flavor, self.logger)
                thread.setName(build_flavor)
                thread.start()
                threads.append(thread)
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()
            vmware_create()
            openstack_create()
```

Unfortunately, after the threads are .join()'d, I'm calling vmware_create() and openstack_create() in serial. I'd like to be able to execute each of those after their respective threads complete so that I'm not waiting for both threads to finish before starting one of the *_create() functions...and then waiting for the first to complete before executing the 2nd

i.e. right now vmware_create() will execute only after BOTH threads are finished, and once vmware_create() is done, only then will openstack_create() begin. I'd like to be able to wait for the respective threads to complete, and then execute the _create() function for whatever thread completed first, all the while waiting for the 2nd thread to finish and then once that's done, immediately executing its _create() function for true parallelization.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this and need a lil help.

Comment: Why don't you call them from the thread?

Comment: @user193661 yeah that would be preferable, and the answer below from Mike Muller seems to have worked. I think I just needed an outside perspective, as I couldn't figure out how to do it, but Mike seems to have a very nice working solution. Not sure why my question was downvoted...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions are objects. Just hand them to the thread:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, command, template, env, build_flavor, logger, func=None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.command = command
        self.template = template
        self.env = env
        self.build_flavor = build_flavor
        self.logger = logger
        self.func = func

    def run(self):
        self.logger.info('Running (%s)...this may take several minutes. Please be patient' % self.build_flavor)
        run_command(self.command, self.template, self.env)
        self.logger.info('Complete (%s)' % self.build_flavor)
        # call func if it is there
        if self.func:
            self.func()
        return
```

Now, I supply the first two threads with function to call:

```
if self.build_type == 'default':
    threads = []
    funcs = {0: vmware_create, 1: openstack_create}
    for i, t in enumerate(self.template):
        modify_template(t)
        build_flavor = self.getmatch(t)
        func = funcs.get(i, None)
        thread = MyThread(packer, t, self.new_env, build_flavor, 
                          self.logger, func=func)
        thread.setName(build_flavor)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

Of course, you can add them to any other threads.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I couldn't figure out how to call the appropriate function based on what thread was being executed, but that does indeed seem to work. Cheers!

Comment: Good to hear that it helped. You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.